# Make .xlsx template file available in published .NET Core 2.0 app

Tags: asp.net-core, publish, missing-template

I have a .NET Core 2.0 solution containing 3 projects (DataAccess, Services, WebAPI). In the wwwroot folder of the WebAPI project I've created a templates folder that contains a couple of Excel template files. In Services I have an Export folder which contains the ExportService. The ExportService uses the templates to generate some reports. I have a private method that 'gets' the path to the templates directory. In fact I'm just specifying a relative path to it, which works fine when debugging, but not when I publish the project. How can I make the files available/reachable in my published app?

```
private string GetExcelTemplatePath()
{
    var templatesDirectory = "..\\WebAPI\\wwwroot\\templates";
    var templateName = "Excel_template_v1.xlsx";
    var templatePath = Path.Combine(templatesDirectory, templateName);

    return templatePath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With ASP.NET Core you’ll want to inject `IHostingEnvironment` into your controller (or wherever you need this). From that object you can get `WebRootPath` which contains the path to `wwwroot`. Use that to find the files inside it.

[More information from the web.](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/302/server-mappath-equivalent-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Hi, Sami. Is there no way I can do this from Services? Somebody else worked on the front end part and it's a separate project I don't have access to. I don't want to mess up the whole project...

Comment: @kanpeki I think you can inject it in method calls also, or give it as an argument for the service when it’s created.